# React chartjs 2 How can I get internal Chart.js object to register plugins

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs

At documentation I found that I can access chats.js object from import { Chart } from 'react-chartjs-2';
But at 2.9.0 version there is not Chart object
https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2#chartjs-object

I want use Chart.pluginService.register

Answer (score 4):

Since you install chart.js as a peer dependency with react-chartjs-2 you can simply use the object given by chart.js. Javascript objects work with references, so changing settings there will modify react-chartjs-2.

Example:

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';

Chart.pluginService.register(/* your plugin */);
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively plugins can also be registered using the 'plugins' prop on the chart component you are using. for example:
totalizer is the custom plugin.(Reference: https://jsfiddle.net/simonbrunel/9ezggxx5/)

```
<Bar
  data={ChartData}
  options={newOptions}
  plugins={[totalizer]}
 />
```